# How to receive a bounce if we do not want them emailed

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am trying to figure out, once we send an email to X number of recipients through *Amazon SES*, how are we supposed to receive a bounce message (through *Amazon SNS* or any other tool) if we do not want them to be emailed to another account?

Using the nested labyrinth of Amazon's documentation, I found out one can have your bounces emailed to a specific account. But let us not take that path! The alternative is [Configuring Amazon SNS Notifications for Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-sns-notifications.html#configure-feedback-notifications-api).

Here, Amazon offers two options:

1. Configuring Notifications Using the Amazon SES Console
2. Configuring Notifications Using the Amazon SES API

In the latter approach, Amazon introduces three API methods to deal with and writes

> You can use these API actions to write a customized front-end
>   application for notifications.

Does "*a customized front-end application for notifications*" means setting up a Web server to listen for Bounce and Complaint JSON messages from Amazon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need a webserver to process the bounces, but you do need *something* to process them.

You tell SES which SNS topic to send the bounces too, and then you can subscribe to that SNS topic with a variety of endpoints of your choosing, getting an email is just one of them.

I find it best to let SES Notify SNS, and then have SNS deliver that message to an SQS queue, and I have a services that polls that queue and processes the bounces against my database.

AWS gives you the tools to be notified about bounces, but you still need to do the work of processing the bounce notifications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw on your profile that you are an Amazon expert. Do you know if Amazon is going to add clicks and opens information available in the near future so that we do not need to setup webhooks for them?

Comment: Does this mean I need an SES, an SNS and an SQS account with every installation of my program for different customers?

Comment: You could all share an account, or they could have seperate accounts; really depends on the situation; and no, I don't know about those features - AWS doesn't usually hint at things that might come.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is fairly clear. SES bounce notifications go to an SNS topic. Once you understand that you just need to look at the SNS documentation to see what methods are available to subscribe to an SNS topic. Currently the following methods of receiving SNS messages are available

- Lambda
- SQS
- HTTP/S
- Email
- SMS

So you can have a Lambda function that gets called once for every bounce message. You can have bounce messages added to an SQS queue. You can have an HTTP/S endpoint in your application that bounce messages will get posted to. You can have bounce messages emailed to you. You can have bounce messages sent to your phone as SMS messages.